# Opinions on my Command pattern design - is it extensible?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am implementing a program that takes commands from a user and based on those commands, drives a Robot on a grid. To implement this program I have used the Command pattern. I have used this pattern because, most importantly, I want to be able to add to the list of possible commands in the future.

The program takes a string of commands from the user, and executes those commands, e.g. FFRFLF (forward x 2, turn right, forward, turn left, forward).

Can anyone give me their opinion on the quality of my design?

Robot Controller class:

```
    public void control(){

do{
    process();  
}while(tru);
}

public String process(){

    // 1. Get user input
    String cmds = get user input from console

    // 2. Populate command list
    populateCommandList(cmds);

    // 3. Execute commands
    executeCommands();

       // 4. Display current location of robot
}

public void populateCommandList(String cmds) {

    Command r = new TurnRightCommand(robot);
    Command l = new TurnLeftCommand(robot);
    Command f = new ForwardCommand(robot);

    commands = new ArrayList<Command>();

        for(int i=0; i<cmds.length(); i++){

            char cmd = cmds.charAt(i);
            switch(cmd){
                case 'F': 
                    commands.add(f);
                    break;
                case 'R': 
                    commands.add(r);
                    break;
                case 'L': 
                    commands.add(l);
                    break;
            }   
        }   
}

private void executeCommands() {
    if(commands!=null && commands.size()>0){
        for(Command cmd : commands){
            cmd.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RobotController r = new RobotController();      
        r.control();
    }
}
```

Is this a good design? I need to know if the deign is good and that I can easily add new commands with minimal rework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've added an unnecessary layer of abstraction here.

To me, `populateCommandList` looks completely unnecessary.  You are converting a list of commands in one format (character string) into another format (an array of `Command` objects).  Then, presumably, `executeCommands` just executes all of those command objects in order.  This wastes time and memory by creating a bunch of unnecessary objects.

Why not just have `executeCommands` take the string directly, and execute the appropriate command for each character that it encounters?

In other words, I would have something like this in `executeCommands`:

```
   for(int i=0; i<cmds.length(); i++){
       char cmd = cmds.charAt(i);
         switch(cmd){
            case 'F': 
                robot.move(FORWARD,1);
                break;
            case 'R': 
                robot.turn(RIGHT);
                break;
            case 'L': 
                robot.turn(LEFT);
                break;
        }
   }
```

Either way looks equally extensible to me.  Either way you will have a switch statement somewhere that defines what commands are possible, and that is what you have to change in order to add a new command.